# How to Solve CORS error in accessing laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel, outlook, cors, outlook-addin

Im very new to laravel applications.What im trying to do is developing an outlook web addon that uses the API written in laravel . The problem here is ,it produces the CORS error while accessing API's through outlook mail.

Error :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://test.com/api/test' from origin 'https://localhost:44377' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

What i have tried so far :

- spatia/laravel-cors module installed and tried
- Added this in bootstrap/app.php:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
```

- created CORS class file and added as middleware

And finally end up with the same error.What should I do ?

Edit :

Why it automatically redirect the request to https instead of http .Where it went wrong ? The request url should be http://test.com/api/test ,not https://test.com/api/test

Thanks in advance !

Comment: _“What should I do ?”_ - inform yourself how CORS works … You are making a request to `https://test.com` here, so the server behind _that_ address is what would have to allow the request here.

Comment: @CBroe it is virtual host in my local ,can you elaborate the procedure ?

Comment: So what system is providing the functionality of `https://test.com/api/test`? Is _that_ supposed to be your laravel installation? Or what is it?

Comment: @CBroe As of now ,it just return a string, im using it for a test purpose .if things works well then only ill change the functionality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem, solved it by [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware)

[Define your custom middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#defining-middleware)

```
//App\Http\Middleware;

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type,X-Token-Auth,Authorization')
        ->header('Accept', 'application/json');
}
```

Than just register yours Middleware, local (for specific route/routes) or global.

[How to register Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#registering-middleware)

Notice! Some old brovsers do not support '*' logic

Comment: Check answer again, I found mistake.

Answer (score 7):

I am using Laravel 8

check config/cors.php

change paths array to * ('paths' => ['*'])

Comment: its doesnt work for me using get method and with jwt

Comment: Cors sometime happens due to error in request (token, payload, url etc)

Answer (score 3):

This work for me:

```
php artisan make:middleware OwnCors
```

Code of the Middleware created:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class OwnCors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization'
        ];
        if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
            return response('OK')
                ->withHeaders($headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value)
            $response->header($key, $value);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Add the middlware into your App\Http\Kernel.php

```
    protected $middleware = [
         \App\Http\Middleware\OwnCors::class,
         // Others middlewares
];
```

Comment: the best handle function I've tried

Answer (score 2):

**For Laravel 8**

In my case I added the origin that needs to access the resource.

```
// config/cors.php

// add a path to the resource here if you want it accessible to external origins
// for example no need to explicitly tell allowed origins
// what origins should gain access to api/* routes
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

// explicitly tell which origins needs access to the resource
'allowed_origins' => ['*', 'https://mywebsite.com', 'http://mywebsite.com'],

// or use regex pattern, helpful if you want to grant
// access to origins with certain pattern (i.e. an origin under a subdomain etc.)
'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['/https?:\/\/mywebsite\.com\/?\z/'],

// no changes made below
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => false,
```

Also don't forget to run `php artisan optimize` in case you are caching the config.

Answer (score 0):

Things you need to check if you are developing outlook addon :

- Check whether you have included the domain name  in manifest.xml ,in my case i need to include https://test.com to include in <AppDomain> tag.
- Your domain should have ssl certificate .(ie) outlook allows you to request only through https .

And follow this answer as well : [middleware to solve cors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62510720/11095724)

Answer (score 0):

> From Laravel 8
> for CORS ORIGIN by default **config/cors.php**

If route prefix like bellow

```
Route::middleware('api')->prefix('api/v1/currency')
```

then change path in **config/cors.php**

```
'paths' => ['api/*']
```

or if route like bellow in **config/cors.php**

```
Route::middleware('api')->prefix('currency/api/v1')
```

then change paths array to  `('paths' => ['*'])`

Answer (score -3):

If you are using Laravel 7.0, it already has CORS functionality built in

Comment: using laravel version 6.12

Comment: using v8 but CORS not working from localhost for me ...

Comment: This doesn't explain HOW to do it.

Answer (score -3):

Try this way in your laravel app:

```
php artisan serve --host YOUR_LOCAL_IP
```

`YOUR_LOCAL_IP` is your ip that can access with `ifconfig` command in linux and `ipconfig` in windows.

Finally you should request to `YOUR_LOCAL_IP:PORT/api`

Comment: This isn't useful for production where you might need access from a different origin.