# API Rest Laravel 8 Cors

Tags: php, laravel

I have an API Rest with Laravel 8.12 and a front-end with VueJS, locally I can connect to the API correctly, but when uploading everything to the server where the system will be, which has "Window Server 2012 R2" installed, when trying to consult the end points the API gives cors error, I tried installing laravel cors plugins, creating a middleware and nothing, it does not work always gives cors error.

Also try using the headers

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
```

I put these in the `public/index.php` and `routes/api.php` and it still gives the error.

I do not know if it is the server that is blocking due to some missing configuration, here I do not know completely how it would be done in the ISS.

How could I solve the cors error?

Comment: Does your nginx/apache configuration allow CORS also?

Comment: @Jaquarh I don't know, where can I verify that?

Comment: Try this browser extension: **Moesif Origin Cors Changer**

Comment: I think you should create your midlleware check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62510345/how-to-solve-cors-error-in-accessing-laravel-routes)