# Laravel vue 3 remove /build/ from url

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes

Let me start of with the fact that im new to laravel and english is not my main language so dont mind my grammer. I have a project that has a laravel api with a vue front-end. The Laravel web routing redirects everything to a single blade file that contains the vue app. this way i can use the vue routing. This is has all been working fine for a while now but now im trying to build for production and ive run into the following issue.

after using npm run build to build for production laravel puts /build/ to every route im using through vue. This is very logical given that it uses the build folder in the public directory like it should. But its ofcourse verry ugly for the users. Is there a way to remove the /build/ from the url? (appart from redirecting /build/ to / in the .htacces file on the server)

Comment: You must create a CORS middleware [use this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62510720/8509638)

Answer (score 4):

You can set the environment variables in .env file for javascript using **VITE_** prefix as below:

Please add the new environment variable in .env file as below:

```
VITE_BASE_URL="/"
```

Made the router related changes in your Vue file as below:

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL || '/'),
  routes: [
    .....
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem from `import.meta.env.BASE_URL` in vitejs, in build mode this `import.meta.env.BASE_URL` result "/build/" and development mode result, is "/"

I don't know where to change this, but I fix this problem with

```
const router = createRouter({
history: createWebHistory("/"),
routes: [
    {
     ......
    }
]
```

})

and fix it